# Getting 404 (Page Not Found) error while calling Controller Action from Jquery in Zend Framework

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, zend-framework

I'm new to Zend-Framework and i'm trying to call action method from indexController.php file using Jquery, that time i'm getting Error :

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost/zf_demo/public/index/process

My Code is : IndexController.php

public function processAction() {
    echo "Successfully Called processAction";
}
```

And  I'm calling this action using following Code :

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",           
        url: "http://localhost/zf_demo/public/index/process",
        success: function() {
            alert("AJAX call a success!");
        },
        error: function() {
              alert("AJAX call an epic failure");
        }
    });
```

.htaccess File :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

For More Help :

1 ) application.ini

```
[production]

phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 0
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
appnamespace = "Application"
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1



[testing : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1

[development : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1

[config]
resources.db.adapter = PDO_MYSQL
resources.db.isDefaultAdapter = true
resources.db.params.host = localhost
resources.db.params.username = root
resources.db.params.password = 
resources.db.params.dbname = pankaj_test
```

2) Bootstrap.php

```
class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{
    protected function _initController()
    {
        $this->_frontcontroller = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
        $this->_frontcontroller->setControllerDirectory(APPLICATION_PATH . 'controllers/');
    }

    protected function _initRoute()
    {
        $this->_route = $this->_frontcontroller->getRouter();
        $this->_route->addRoute('default', new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
            ':controller/:action/*', array(
                'module'     => 'default',
                'controller' => 'index',
                'action'     => 'index'
            )
        ));
    }


    public function run()
    {
        try {
            $this->_frontcontroller->dispatch();
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            print nl2br($e->__toString());
        }
    }

    protected function _initDb()
    {
      $configData=array(
            'database' => array(            
            'adapter' => 'Pdo_Mysql',           
            'params' => array(          
                            'host' => 'localhost',                          
                            'username' => 'root',                           
                            'password' => '',                           
                            'dbname' => 'pankaj_test')
            )
        );

        $config=new Zend_Config($configData);

        $db=Zend_Db::factory($config->database);

        //$db = Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::getDefaultAdapter();

        Zend_Db_Table::setDefaultAdapter($db);





    }

}
```

My index.php(From public folder)

```
<?php

// Define path to application directory

defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
    || define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../application'));

// Define application environment
defined('APPLICATION_ENV')
    || define('APPLICATION_ENV', (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : 'development'));

// Ensure library/ is on include_path
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'),
    get_include_path(),
)));

/* Zend_Application */
require_once 'Zend/Application.php';

// Create application, bootstrap, and run
$application = new Zend_Application(
    APPLICATION_ENV,
    APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini'
);

$application->bootstrap()
            ->run();
?>
```

Comment: missing htaccess with rewrite?

Comment: plz check now...i have added the code.

Comment: Does it work if you access it directly in the browser, not with Ajax?

Comment: no...at that time i get the Error : The requested URL /zf_demo/public/index/process was not found on this server

Comment: If you try to access the page localhost/zf_demo/public/index/process directly in your browser, does it work ?

Comment: @joellord : no, that time also i get the same error 404 error...

Comment: @joellord : one more thing that 404 error is of apache and not of zend...

Comment: Which server are you using? apache? and what is the result when you call http://localhost/zf_demo/public/ in your browser

Comment: @Amit : Yes, I'm using Apache server and after calling "localhost/zf_demo/public" it shows my view page perfectly.

Comment: then i guess your .htaccess has a problem. I wouldn't be too sure about that though but give this one a shot http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5776509/apache-mod-rewrite-enabled-but-not-working

Comment: Also you can make sure if your .htaccess has error by using this url http://localhost/zf_demo/public/index.php/index/process if this one works then .htaccess is the culprit

Comment: @Amit: Still not working by using this url  "localhost/zf_demo/public/index.php/index/process" directly in browser

Comment: Why are you using ZF1 if you're new to ZF? You should start with ZF2, ZF1 is a thing of the past.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be so much easier if you specified a virtual host in your local server.

Edit apache's httpd.conf and add (at the end of file):

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.15:80>
    ServerName 127.0.0.15
    DocumentRoot "C:\zf_demo\public" // or whatever is the path to the index.php

    <Directory "C:\zf_demo\public"> // you might need to modify this part 
        DirectoryIndex index.php    // depending on Apache's version in use
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

RESTART YOUR SERVER.

Now, change in your $.ajax call:

```
url: "http://localhost/zf_demo/public/index/process",
```

to

```
url: "/index/process",
```

Now run `http://127.0.0.15` and voila!

Answer (score 0):

You need to omit the word 'public'. So the URL should be:

```
url: "http://localhost/zf_demo/index/process",
```

Comment: comment out _initRoute in your bootstrap and check whether that works.

Comment: @Rijandael : still not working....one more thing that 404 error is of apache and not of zend...does that make any difference..??

Answer (score 0):

Have you disabled the view?
Also layout should be disabled, if its enabled by default.
You can work around this by adding exit to the end of your action.

```
public function processAction() {
    echo "Successfully Called processAction";
    exit;
}
```

Also check that APPLICATION_ENV is development not production. Otherwise it will not display errors.

Finally check that your .htaccess file is ok by visiting `http://localhost/zf_demo/public/index.php/index/process` . if this works than .htaccess has a problem.

Comment: as u said i have added 'exit' at the end of my 'processAction()'...but still it doesn't work :(

Comment: and also i have changed APPLICATION_ENV to 'development' from 'production' in my index.php

Comment: For your more referance i will post my index.php, please check if there is any more bugs in that.